# Which console systems can indie developers officially develop for?

Tags: console

As an independent developer, I would like to know what platforms I can use to reach what consoles, and under what prices. I'm assuming a small team (1-3 people) and low or non-existent budget (under $1000).

For the purpose of this question, a "console" is "anything other than a PC." So this includes mobiles phones and other devices.

For this question to be useful and not a collection of every game engine and platform in the world, maybe we should restrict it to technologies that support at least two platforms.

Answer (score 9):

XNA can deploy to a Windows 7 Phone and Xbox 360.

Comment: And desktop as well.

Comment: Not to mention you can port it to other platforms:  http://andrewrussell.net/exen/   or   http://www.monoxna.org/

Comment: Thanks for that link, I had no idea it was able to port to other platforms!

Comment: Adding on to Jon's comment: http://monogame.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5):

[Android](http://developer.android.com/index.html) is how I got started with game development. It's completely free to develop for and has a one time $25 fee to upload to the Android Market.

Answer (score 4):

**iOS:** You only need $199 per year to deploy on the App Store.
This includes $99 per year for membership in the iOS Developer Program, plus $500 every five years to buy a Mac mini once Apple stops producing new versions of macOS and Xcode for the old model.
Cocos2d is a free 2d engine and chipmunk or box2d for physics engines.
For 3D there is NinevehGL and cocos2d is releasing a 3d engine (yes, the name is cocos3d)

**Android:** You can deploy to android with the PC you already have and a one-time $25 fee. There is a cocos2d version for android, but I think it's not as advanced as the IPhone one. You can check andengine to.

You have XNA for xbox and windows phone and it cost $99 to deploy on XBox and windows phone.

Using unity do deploy on android and IPhone cost $800 ($400 each). I guess this is a bit expensive for your budget but it's still a good option for indie development.

I think the only technologies that work on multiple platforms with almost no work are XNA and Unity.

Comment: Note that most iPhone development requires a Mac, so if you only have Windows machines you should tack on the non-negligible cost of a Macintosh computer. There are ways around that such as various packagers for Windows-accessible development systems.